# What to look for in a new water radiator?

Tags: water, heating, water-heater, central-heating, radiator

The water radiators I have under each window are 50 years old, and I would like some new ones. They measure HxLxD 50x100x20 cm.

The new ones I would like should be as thin as possible.

I live in an apartment, so a thermostat needs to be mounted on it.

**Question**

Are there things to be aware of when buying radiators?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of companies that make very low profile radiators such as [this one](http://www.runtalnorthamerica.com/residential_radiators/wallpanel-vlx-radiators.html):

[image: runtal radiator]

There are several factors such as the type of system - steam, hot water; if steam, whether one pipe or two.  You will also have to accomodate certain valves, so placement is an issue - piping through the wall or from the floor, whether you can accomodate valves in the wall, and how to access if you do.

Size is also a significant consideration and you need to determine how much area you need to replace a much more massive old radiator.  While the new ones may be more efficient, you may need more surface area, depending on the overall demand for heat.